# Performance Penalty in DynamoDB Because Of Conditional Put

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

We're trying to decide if Conditional Put is the right choice for one of our high throughput use cases.

Its enough for us to be able to say "Insert an item only if no other item exists for same Partition Key and Sort Key values".

We're trying to see how much performance penalty this would have over unconditional puts. Does anyone know if Conditional Puts are slower than Unconditional Puts? If they are, by how much?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to find out is always to measure for your specific use case.

Having said that it’s most likely not appreciably slower than a regular PUT. All of the data needed for a conditional PUT exists on the exact node(s) where the data will end up being stored, and the conditions available are very basic so I doubt there would ever be a significant performance difference.

Comment: The first part of this answer is very correct. You should measure for your specific use case.

But the second part is very misleading. DynamoDb is a distributed system. Conditional put promises a certain level of atomicity to the update. So all the nodes that needs to be updated should have some kind of quorum to agree on a value to prevent any race condition. I don't know the exact overhead, but there is definitely overhead on this. It is not as simple as reading the data before writing.

Comment: @infiniteRefactor -- DynamoDB doesn't work on a quorum system. Instead, there is a leader for each shard at any time. The other two are just failover (and read replicas).  So, the original poster is correct. All the data required is available on the leader node.

Note, this also makes DynamoDB a CP system instead of an AP system (in the CAP theorem sense).

But, OPs original advice stands. Test your use case.

Comment: Yeah, from Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_DynamoDB#Data_structures - 



'Within each partition, one of the three nodes is designated the "leader node". All write operations travel first through the leader node before propagating, which makes writes consistent in DynamoDB.'